# I MUST know the amount of RAM in the iPad before buying. What are my options?

Tags: ipad, memory

In the official [iPad page](https://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/), no information is currently provided about the amount of RAM available for any of the iPad devices.

I called Apple just now and the engineer with whom I spoke said that he was not allowed to give me official numbers.

He suggested that mac tracker, a 3rd party web-site, suggested the following

iPad Pro: 6 GB
iPad Air: 4 GB

I do not trust 3rd srty information.
I must buy.
I must have this information before I buy.
Apple refuses to give it to me. (God knows why. This is ridiculous.)

Too little RAM is the reason why my current iPad sucks. Apps are constantly forced to reset because of this. And the alternatives suck because Apple uses its monopoly power to kill viable competitors. This is intolerable.

What are my options?

Comment: This is something [Wikipedia does better than Ask Different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad#Model_comparison). Is there a practical question you seek that depends on RAM or this resource being documented? Seems like a trivia question, but please discuss on [meta] if the classification as off site resource isn’t correct.

Comment: So this is life under a corporate coup eh? Where calling attention to Apple’s refusal to disclose the amount of RAM in their product is vorbotten. How much are the moderators being paid by Apple?

Comment: Hiding the amount of RAM in a computer is unheard of. I want to know how much is in it before I buy. Less RAM is a horrible user experience. This is a legitimate question. RE-OPEN THE QUESTION!

Comment: You already got three recommendations for applications/web sites which provide the information you seek. We are not Apple, nevertheless questions about why Apple does or doesn't do things are off-topic because there can't be fact-based answers on them and all you'll get are opinions. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for details.

Comment: Please reread the comments and answers you've got so far. Apple doesn't publish the information you are looking for so relying on 3rd parties is the best option here. If you want to reach out to Apple about this use their published contact channels. Ranting about Apple corporate policy on a site focused on technical problem solving will not change that policy (nor will it improve the answers you get).

Answer (score 3):

There is an app on the App Store named MacTracker. This app lists info about Macs, iPad and other mac devices. This may also exist as a web site as you mentioned before. The information in Mac Tracker is as accurate as any other site other than Apple itself.

You can also lookup the specs of iPad models on https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/index-ipad-specs.html.

Comment: Thanks. So physically going to the Apple Store and using the app on each sounds like an option. Unfortunately they are all closed in my are due to COVID-19.

Comment: @AlexRyan MacTracker provides information on all Apple devices, it doesn't need to be run on the specific device. You can also just look up device specs on https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/index-ipad-specs.html